# AnguarJS - Nested Array Empty when Accessed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm going nuts!

My server responds with some JSON at an endpoint.  It's something like this:

```
[{
  key: 'value'
  nested: [{
    key: 'value'
  ]}
}]
```

If I access that endpoint directly in my browser, I can confirm I get this properly structured JSON object (from Laravel).

My AngularJS app accesses it like normal:

```
$http.get('endpoint').success(function(data){
    $scope.datas = data;
});
```

**Here's the problem** : My object in AngularJS the nested array is *always* empty unless I return my JSON as a single object instead of an array like this:

```
{datas: [{
  key: 'value'
  nested: [{
    key: 'value'
  ]}
}]}
```

In AngularJS, I can now see the nested array.  **but wait**, if I try to access it like

```
ng-repeat(data in datas.datas)
```

It's *empty again!*.

Here's the Javascript/HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="order in orders">
    <div ng-repeat="message in order.messages">[[ message.value ]]</div>
</div>

msmService.controller('ordersCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http){
    var refresh = function(){
        $http.get('/admin/service/orders').success(function(data){
            $scope.orders = data;
        });
    };

    refresh();
});
```

Comment: I think the problem is how you try to get the data from your backend. Make your `$http.get` calls with asynch - calls -> Promises in angularjs, only a suggestion

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: so, you have an array with an object, seems like you need `data[0]`

Comment: Can you now post a ample of real JSON which doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I'll create a jsfiddle right now.

Comment: The JSON you posted is not valid, you are missing the `,`. Moreover, you need curly brackets to print scope variables like `{{ message.value }}`

Comment: I had this in a div ng-class="{danger: order.messages.pop().sender == 'Customer'}"

Comment: I was popping off the array!  OMG SORRY GUYS.  Deleting question...

Comment: @DonJuwe https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged some things and hope this example is what you are looking for:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.orders = {
      datas: [
        {
          key: 'value',
          nested: [
            {
              key: 'nestedValue'
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  
  <div ng-repeat="order in orders.datas">
    {{order.key}}
    <div ng-repeat="message in order.nested">{{message.key}}</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```